# New object vs. overwriting existing object

Tags: c#, performance

I'm working on a c# programm, but my question is more or less cross language.

Assume a class

```
public class Class1
{
  SlimMath.Vector3 location;
}
```

This vector is to hold the location, which im reading directly from an array once per tick.
Now i've two different ways to "overwrite" this vector.

```
void overwrite()
{
    location = new SlimMath.Vector3(cameraData.loc[0], cameraData.loc[1], cameraData.loc[2]);
}
```

and (assume the vector location is initialised also):

```
void overwrite()
{
   location.X = cameraData.loc[0];
   location.Y = cameraData.loc[1];
   location.Z = cameraData.loc[2];
}
```

So after searching in the internet for my own, my question is: Does it even matter if i create a `new SlimMath.Vector3` or overwrite the already existing one, every time I read the input? Due to the fact that I read very often I'd like to know, which approach is the more viable one if it comes to performance.

Thanks in advance for any help on this topic.

Comment: Performance and "good" programming are 2 entirely seperate things, often contradicting eachother wildly. What might be beatiful in code could perform really poor. 

As always with performance you should measure your problems and solve that instead of preemptively sovling issues you dont have.

Comment: @TJHeuvel edited to performance only :).

Comment: Try searching the code instead of the internet for that matter. Run test cases. Check for performance differences.

Comment: Is that vector a struct or a class?

Comment: @usr: [It's a struct](https://code.google.com/p/slimmath/source/browse/trunk/SlimMath/Vector3.cs). An evil mutable one as well.

Comment: @Joey would you explain "evil" to me :)?

Comment: Is there more than one thread involved? Because if there is, the second approach looks like it's highly likely that the other threads might read a `location` with, say, the old Z value and the new X and Y values (although, in the absence of fences, you're not even guaranteed that it won't be an old X value and new Y and Z values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more readable approach is to use immutable objects. It is easier to mentally comprehend what happens when you read the code if you can assume that object's properties will not change because of some other piece of code you're not look at currently.

However, sometimes indeed this can lead to a large number of objects created, which *can* *sometimes* decrease performance of your application.

Because of the words "can" and "sometimes" above, usually it is not good to assume by yourself that this particular part of your code will surely be a performance problem.

So, usually you should first write readable and reasonable code and **only** after you'll pin point a particular performance problem (best using a profiler both for execution time and memory consumption) you can apply some "hacks" here and there fix it.